# Blackberry verticalfield manager issue

Tags: blackberry

In a vertical Field Manager with `sublayout()`, `paint()` and `manager.add(field)` what is the flow of execution?
I mean - which portion will be executed first and which one will be executed last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, assuming we start monitoring the flow from the `manager.add(field)`, this call makes the manager to 1) relayout itself and 2) repaint. So in my vision the order should be:

1. `manager.add(field)`
2. `sublayout()`
3. `paint()`

A tip: you could just override those methods and add some logging messages you are able to monitor. Or by using a debugger with stop points put in those methods you could get the flow.